# Getting error: AssertEquals is not public cannot be accessed from outside

Tags: java, maven, junit5

I added the maven framework to my java project. Create a java class under src/test/java/XTest.java. When using assertEquals, it shows a red mark in the Intellij idea and the import statement. 
It shows the following error : 
`'org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals' is not public in 'org.junit.jupiter.api'. Cannot be accessed from outside package`

Tried mvn clean and restarting Intellij by invalidating cache 
This is the pom.xml file I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit5-jupiter-starter-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${maven.compiler.source}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.8.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you show some of your code? Looks like you just used the wrong import.

Answer (score 2):

The correct import is

> org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals

instead of

> org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals

An example of use is

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

class MainTest {
    
    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals("Expected", "Actual");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right. The current import is `import static org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals;  and that got automatically generated when I pressed Alt+Enter on `assertEquals` and Intellij showed two libraries to import from. I see now that one imports the above wrong one and the other imports the correct one. Why could that be happening?
`

Comment: Not sure what happened, in my case the wrong import appears only if I press Alt+Enter when I do it without parameters, eg assertEquals().
When parameters are available, eg assertEquals(1, 2), I have only the correct import suggested.